# How can i make responsive bootstrap elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone help me to divide a screen to 8 responsive parts (2 on top , 2 in the middle and 2 on the bottom) with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create three rows and split them into two halves each. Something like this

```
<div class="container ">
     <div class=" row">
         <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
         <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
      </div>
     <div class=" row">
         <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
         <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
      </div>
      <div class=" row">
         <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
         <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">  </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">                  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">  </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">                  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">  </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">                  </div>
   </div>
```

place contents inside the div having `col-md-3` class